# How to resolve the problem of ClientException: XMLHttpRequest error

Tags: flutter, dart, http

Im try to Call the HTTP request for flutter web application showing error:
ClientException: XMLHttpRequest error., uri=http:192.168.xxx.xxx;xxx

In my test I used web (Chrome) as my target platform.

**Im using flutter http package.**

My backend is nodeja and data base is mongodb

Comment: That `uri` doesn't look valid.